Dual of Quadratic Programming with inequality constraints
I am new to duality concepts and I was reading a document that dualizes the following problem:
\begin{equation}
\min_{x,y} \ ||x-y||^2
\\s.t. \ A_x x \leq b_x, \ A_y y \leq b_y
\end{equation}
into:
\begin{equation}
\max_{\lambda_1,\lambda_2} \ -\lambda_1^Tb_x -\lambda_2^Tb_y
\\s.t. \lambda_1^TA_x + \lambda_2^Tb_y = 0,
\\ ||A_y^T\lambda_2|| \leq 1,
\\ \lambda_1 \geq 0, \ \lambda_2 \geq 0
\end{equation}
I can't seem to grasp why the constraint $||A_y^T\lambda_2|| \leq 1$ (which is the case when the cost is $||x-y||$) and not $||A_y^T\lambda_2|| \leq ||x-y||$. Could someone please help me out?
Thank you for your help in advance

is the document available online? If so, can you share the link?

Yes it is. This is the one: https://hybrid-robotics.berkeley.edu/publications/ICRA2022_PolytopeCBF_DiscreteTime.pdf
